# How did Brianna recognise her mother's ring?

Tags: plot-explanation, outlander

Spoiler alert: Stop reading now if you haven't seen season 4.

Soon after Brianna goes back in time to find her parents, she notices a distinctive ring in the possession of Stephen Bonnet and immediately recognises it as her mother's.

However, this ring was made after Jamie commissions a silversmith to make it after Claire returns to the past having left Brianna in modern times.

The only way Brianna could have recognised it is if the ring survived 200 years and was somehow made known to her as having belonged to Claire in the past.

Is this a plot error? If not, how did she come to know what the ring looked like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ring that Bonnet stole was Claire's original wedding band that she was given when she wed Jamie Fraser in the past during her first trip. When she came back to the present, she wore Frank's ring (Gold) on her left hand, and the simple silver circle from Jamie on her right hand.

The original ring caused readers some displeasure, because it did not match the one described in the books. This was rectified when the new one was commissioned, and created with the filigrees to match the book description.

So the one that Claire wore while raising Brianna was the original ring that Jamie had made for her, not the replacement one he commissioned after Bonnet stole it.

[Here is a video](https://youtu.be/ZB3hMv-MuGk) that shows the original ring (S1E7) at the :48 second mark, and another [composite video](https://www.ign.com/articles/2018/11/09/outlander-season-4-premiere-stephen-bonnet-claire-ring) (Oddly, also at the :48 second mark) that shows the same ring each time.